# CLI password prompt for Cordova with build.json

Tags: android, cordova, code-signing

The documentation [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#using-buildjson) says `For release signing, passwords can be excluded and the build system will issue a prompt asking for the password.` which is a feature I'm trying to take advantage of because it would allow me to automate part of the build process without having to put passwords in the git repository.

Here's my build.json:

```
{
    "android": {
        "release": {
            "keystore": "path/to.keystore",
            "storePassword": "",
            "alias": "alias_name",
            "password" : "",
            "keystoreType": "JKS"
        }
    }
}
```

The build fails with the error message `Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`. It doesn't give me a prompt to type/paste the passwords.

I tried empty strings as shown above to match the example in the documentation and I tried omitting the properties, both with the same results. I double-checked the path to the keystore, the alias, and the keystore type and they are correct; changing the path and type both cause the command to fail with a different error message.

Nothing obvious appears to be working. Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: Have a look at this link - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12159 It should work fine in latest version i guess

Answer (score 0):

Same issue and as mentioned in comments [this commit](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12159) should have fixed the problem but I updated to cordova 6 today and am still encountering this bug. For now you can just put your passwords in the build.json and it will build, just don't forget to remove them before committing. Hopefully they will patch/repatch this soon.